British actor offered chance to relive his life
I'm looking for a color movie I saw on cable TV in 2014. I think the cast are all unknowns. 
British actor loses the love of his life and his career is floundering when he meets two strange men in the park on a rainy day. I think this Is set in England. The men hold umbrellas. I think the actor lives on a street that closes once a year for a festival. They offer him a chance to relive his life and he accepts. More than once i think. He becomes a famous actor (  TV Soap I think).  He finds true love near the movie end and all is fine. However, 
At the very end...

  the girl he used to love meets the same two men and they offer her that same chance.


Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.
